# Python How to keep running same function multiple times parallel with different arguments in API

Tags: python, api, flask, multiprocessing

I am using flask-restx api

There is a function called 'predict_y'.
I have to load a specific NLP deep learning module into var X and use it to predict labels in text in var Y.

I would get a POST request with values for x and y where x is the name of the deep learning model I need to load(time-consuming) and y is the text I have been given with the model used to predict a label and return the label.

I want the whole process to be fast. But loading the model into var x after getting a request is very time consuming.

```
Post request body = {"x":"model1", "y":"Text for label prediction with model1"}

def predict_y(x,y):
  x = model.load(path/to/models/x)
  answer = x.predict(y)
  return answer
```

Is there a way I could keep running the same function  'predict_y' multiple times with different loaded models in x.

This way, when I receive POST request for suppose x= model1 and  y= 'Predict this text's label', I could redirect this into func 'predict_y' where a var x has the already loaded model1.

These function could be stopped once the last request received for them has a timeout.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to load the models outside your `predict` function, when the flask app starts, for example in a `dict`, you can then reference the correct model inside your `predict`.

```
Post request body = {"x":"model1", "y":"Text for label prediction with model1"}

models = {x: model.load(f"path/to/models/{x}") for x in ["model1", "model2", ...]}

def predict_y(x,y):
  x = models[x]
  answer = x.predict(y)
  return answer
```

Comment: I cannot keep loaded models in the dictionary like that because their size is big and there are many models to be used. Is there a way to load only models currently being used and remove them from cache once they have not been in use for a certain amount of time?

Comment: I don't see a solution that will keep your app performant, apps like these generally either have enough memory to hold all models or each model has it's own separate flask app hosted on a separate machine. One thing you could try is dynamically loading each model as it's needed and unloading it when you're short on memory. This will still drastically slow down your app with high random traffic though.

Comment: Would you know about spawning model servers at endpoints listening to a port. for a particular model that one server would return a response and would close after a certain time of no usage? This was a another advice given to me in person but I cannot quite fully understand it